# Background image not covering the whole page

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to place an image in my website behind everything that's in my header and a little more, but there's a problem with doing that. 
I've tried placing the image like this:

```
body {
  background-image:url('images/city.jpg');
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}
```

But the result is in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnDPM.png).

There's always a problem with the 'SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY' part, either the image pushes it down or it doesn't allow the image to extend above it.

This is the HTML for the "SMS..." text:

```
<h1 class="n1">
  <font face="ralewaybold">
    SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY
  </font>
</h1>
```

And the CSS:

```
.n1 { 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  margin-top: 10em;
}
```

The whole page screenshot:
[image: The whole page screenshot]

I want the image to reach the top of the page - https://prnt.sc/qh4foe

Comment: Please, post css and html for 'SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY'?

Comment: Hi, you are limiting the body height to 500px. Try with percentage like the whole height  give it a value100%. Also the margin:0px  . Try this and see. Please specify what device you are using ( what browser device such as iphone, desktop or anroid ) and what browser ( safari, chrome, firefox ..)

Comment: @MorticiaA.Addams `code`<h1 class="n1"><font face="ralewaybold">SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY</font></h1> `code`.n1 { display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10em;}  `code`

Comment: @AlanM When I try to extend it, it just extends downwards, it doesn't go over the SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY text. I'm using chrome.

Comment: You can try to use this to cover the whole page:

body {
  background-image:url('images/city.jpg');
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: @Poszer Still no result, it just extends downwards all the way until the end of the page. Screenshot of the whole page, minimized - [link]https://imgur.com/a/iHuNMnu

Comment: @Cubex Try to set this please:

  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url('images/city.jpg')


You want something like this, right ? 

https://prnt.sc/qh4ehn

Comment: @Poszer Still the same old problem. I want the image to reach the top of the page and then edit the image how I want - gradient etc. I want it to be like this - https://prnt.sc/qh4foe But for some weird reason, the image just doesn't go above the 'SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY' text.

Comment: Ok, let's try than like this @Cubex:

     body {
          background-image: url(images/city.jpg);
          background-position: center center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
        }

And also add this css:

    body {
      background: url(images/city.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
    }

Comment: @Poszer Still the same problem. https://prnt.sc/qh4lr7 - It seems that it only covers the part where the paragraphs are and the first header. The margin shouldn't effect it, right?

Comment: One more try, try to change background-size:cover; to background-size:100% 100%; @Cubex

Comment: When you delete 'SMS MESSAGING MADE EASY' is background ok? I try simple code and it's ok. Maybe problem is from another part of css. My test: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GADX6YF9V8IP

Comment: @Poszer Ok, wait. Apparently, the margin was the problem, but now there's another problem - How do I make the image so it covers up the little white edges - https://prnt.sc/qh4rf6 at the top, left, right.

Comment: @MorticiaA.Addams For some reason, the margin of the SMS.. text was the problem.

Comment: @Cubex

Setting the body's margin to 0 might fix that problem:

body { margin: 0px; }

Comment: Nice, glad to help you @Cubex

Comment: @Poszer Sorry, but I've got another problem. For some reason when I change the image opacity, the text opacity which is below the image changes too. https://prnt.sc/qh4z9c As if the image and the content is somehow linked.

Comment: Take your image into an image editor, turn down the opacity, save it as a .png and use that instead. @Cubex